# getBaseDir lib issues - call to undefined function

Tags: php

Right now I'm running into an error "Call to undefined function geoip_open()" on one of the lines of my files.

The line is

```
$geoip = geoip_open(Mage::getBaseDir('lib').DS.'MaxMind/GeoIP/data/'.Mage::getStoreConfig('onepagecheckout/geo_ip/city_file'),GEOIP_STANDARD);
```

So I have the file inside of lib/MaxMind/GeoIP/data and it throws this error. Is this because it's not finding the file? Or some other issue with GeoIP?

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about MaxMind GeoIP.

Answer (score 1):

geoip_open is not a core php function therefore it must be define/included before you can call/use it.

Take a look at [Fatal error call to undefined function geoip_open()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13985570/fatal-error-call-to-undefined-function-geoip-open)

```
include("include/geoip.inc");

$gi = geoip_open("include/GeoIP.dat", GEOIP_STANDARD);
```